# How to resolve Property does not exist on type '{}' issue in typescript / firestore project?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Below is some code in my typescript project:

```
admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc(postId).get().then((data) => {

        let likesCount = data.data()?.likesCount || 0;
        let likes = data.data()?.likes || [];
        let updateData = {};

        if (action == 'like') {
            updateData['likesCount'] = ++likesCount;
            updateData[`likes.${userId}`] = true;
        } else {
            updateData['likesCount'] = --likesCount;
            updateData[`likes.${userId}`] = false;
        }

        admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc(postId).update(updateData).then(() => {
            response.status(200).send('Done');
        }).catch((err) => {
            response.status(err.code).send(err.message);
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        response.status(err.code).send(err.message);
    });
```

I am copying this from a tutorial, but I'm getting an error when I'm trying to assign values within the if & else blocks.

Here is the error messages I am getting:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
>   '"likesCount"' can't be used to index type '{}'.   Property
>   'likesCount' does not exist on type '{}'.
>
> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
>   'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.   No index signature with a
>   parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

I've tried creating an interface & using that like below:

```
interface UpdateData {
            likesCount: number,
            likes: string
        }

        let updateData = {} as UpdateData;
```

But that just gives me an error like this:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
>   'string' can't be used to index type 'UpdateData'.   No index
>   signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type
>   'UpdateData'.

Also, the problem I think using this interface is that there are more than these 2 values associated with the ***data*** that I'm getting from firestore, so I still want that data to be exist after updating these 2 values.

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:

```
interface UpdateData {
            likesCount: number;
            likes: string;
            [key:any]: any;
        }
```

It declares that we can have a property of type string and can be used as indexable signature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried using your interface. The error on `updateData['likesCount]` is gone, but here is the new error now on `updateData[`likes.${userId}`]`: Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'string | number'. 

I tried changing string|number to boolean, but that creates a different error again.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I have changed it to any to resolve all issue. But you can change it to a union of multiple data types if you are aware of your structure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're facing a problem with TypeScript classes in general, not with firebase.
So, why don't you give my next solution a try?

```
export class UpdateData {
    constructor(){
        this.likes = {};
    }
    likesCount!: number;
    likes!: {
        [key: string]: boolean;
    }
}
```

and then after fetching data

```
let updateData = new UpdateData();

updateData.likesCount = action == 'like' ? ++likesCount : --likesCount;
updateData.likes[`${userId}`] = action == 'like';

console.log(updateData);
```

P.S. just used conditional statements instead of an if-else block in terms of simplicity, however, your blocks should work just fine.

you can find here an online working example as well: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FUwBMUzAAiBKcA3gLABQcdiEAdmjFAK4IzQAUAlFbXpCYACwCWaAHRIxAa2CYAvBQC+AbhpCVm+jPloAwhDaMYAQgBccRmwC2AI2BQNgunoWWKOoXQDa8gE8rFigxRgBzAF0rewgIJGAURhctGm1qGgB6TNw7WwC4fBgUGgT4FE4xJjhlAHJ3WpcyuHdDY1MauABGJuB4NjQnAElcTtqUewQugCYAZkaaUr64NjwCYlJOxmAAd2w1whJivhcaVaKN4uk5BSMTeGUKmCrGGrqGuAB+OABqH9a7h0rABaYEA9owFzndZHFDXfS+AAGABJyANhrgVIjIp0ni83nB6jcFhlqAgmGh4sBpBBwtxoYdSLw1EA

Hopefully, that helps!